# how to run tomcat and http together in plesk server

Tags: apache, tomcat6, plesk

I want to run java and php script in same server.

I want to run both the port 8080 and 80 in the same server.

Please anyone can you help me how to configure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think your idea is feasible because a server can only listen to 1 port. [Here](http://www.bserban.org/2009/08/configure-apache-and-tomcat-severs-together/) you find a good overview how you can run a Apache HTTPd and Apache Tomcat in parallel on one port.

Please give us some details what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks markus I used the proxy to change the port.
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 0):

If you try it change tomcat port number in using connector to redirect port number it may be chance to work.